# RichTextBlock Styling in C#

Tags: c#, uwp, richtextblock

I have a string in the format:

```
<strong>some text</strong> more text <strong> even more text </strong>
```

I would like to make the text surrounded by the strong tags bold in my richtextblock.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

*Xaml*

```
<RichTextBlock>
    <Paragraph>
        <Bold>Some Text</Bold> more text
        <Bold>Some other text</Bold>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

**EDIT**

Presuming you have a `Grid` called **LayoutGrid** something like this should work

*C#*

```
var rtb = new RichTextBlock();
var paragraph = new Paragraph();

var bold1 = new Bold();
bold1.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "I am Bold" });
paragraph.Inlines.Add(bold1);

var normalText = new Run() { Text = " I am Normal" };
paragraph.Inlines.Add(normalText);

var bold2 = new Bold();
bold2.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = " I am more Bold" });
paragraph.Inlines.Add(bold2);

rtb.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
LayoutGrid.Children.Add(rtb); //Grid in your xaml
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I do this in C#

Comment: @SagarPatel sorry didnt read the question properly :) have updated answer